# Read and Write into IList from another Class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I made a Class where my IList is located:

```
public class ListTable
{
    private IList<object> rolelist = new List<object>();

    public IList<object> GetList()
    {
        return rolelist;
    }
}
```

Then I added this to my MainWindow and add some stuff into the List:
MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
ListTable rolelist = new ListTable();
private void CheckRights()
{
    IList<object> testlist = myClass.GetList();

    testlist.Add(new object[] { i,                          // 0
    (string)reader["role"],                             // 1
    (int)reader["can_add_kunde"],                       // 2
    (int)reader["can_add_assignment_kunde"],            // 3
    (int)reader["can_delete_kunde"],                    // 4
    (int)reader["can_edit_kunde"],                      // 5
    (int)reader["can_add_firmenkunde"],                 // 6
    (int)reader["can_add_assignment_firmenkunde"],      // 7
    (int)reader["can_delete_firmenkunde"],              // 8
    (int)reader["can_edit_firmenkunde"],                // 9
    (int)reader["can_add_assignment"],                  // 10
    (int)reader["can_delete_assignment"],               // 11
    (int)reader["can_edit_assignment"],                 // 12
    (int)reader["can_add_employee"],                    // 13
    (int)reader["can_delete_employee"],                 // 14
    (int)reader["can_edit_employee"],                   // 15
    (int)reader["can_see_adminpanel"],                  // 16
    (int)reader["can_change_columns_kunden"],           // 17
    (int)reader["can_change_columns_firmenkunden"],     // 18
    (int)reader["can_change_databaseTables"]            // 19
    });
}
```

now I want to access to this list from another class:
FirmCustomer.xaml.cs

```
private ListTable list;
private void CheckRights(string username)
{
    IList<object> called = list.GetList();
    foreach (object[] item in called)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(item[1].ToString());
    }
}
```

but `called` is always null so it doesn't get the List.

Can someone tell my why it dont get the list? And how to get access to this list whith it's items?

Comment: But in FirmCustomer.xaml.cs i call the list with `private ListTable list` instead of `ListTable list = new ListTable`. Why it's still a copy ?

Comment: @AlbertoSolano `GetList()` isn't returning a copy - any object that isn't a value type is a reference type, so this will return a reference. The problem seems to be that `FirmCustomer` has its own instance of `ListTable`, which doesn't know about the items added by `MainWindow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to share the list between different classes you could make it `static`:

```
public class ListTable
{
    private static IList<object> rolelist = new List<object>();

    public static IList<object> GetList()
    {
        return rolelist;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
IList<object> = ListTable.GetList();
```

As of now you are creating a new `IList<object>` for each `ListTable` instance that you create.

Comment: thx man. U always know the right answer to my questions. This works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the code samples you provided, `MainWindow` and `FirmCustomer` are using two different instances of the `ListTable` class. You have added the items to the instance in `MainWindow`, but the instance in `FirmCustomer` doesn't know anything about the original instance.

When you create an instance of `FirmCustomer`, you should pass the existing instance of `ListTable` to it so that it can read out the values added previously.

Also, when adding the items to the list, the code is probably not doing what you intend it to do. The code you posted will add one `object[]` to the list. You should call `IList.Add()` for each item individually instead of adding them to the array first.

Comment: thx for your answer. Im getting error that converting from `System.Collections.Gerneric.IList<object>` to `System.Collections.IList`
isnt possible. Do you know how to fix that? Im also not sure of using IList or List

Comment: @OJean Those are two different interfaces. You should use `System.Collections.Generic.IList` whenever possible, since that way you can strongly type your list instead of converting everything to `object` first.

Answer (score 1):

declare the field with static keyword it's common for all so, you can get the value add one class get another class. i was made one sample  the code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ReadIList
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            mainclass mc = new mainclass();
            mc.CheckRights();
            secondclass sc = new secondclass();
            sc.CheckRights(string.Empty);
        }
    }
    public class ListTable
    {
        public static  IList<object> rolelist = new List<object>();

        public IList<object> GetList()
        {
            return rolelist;
        }
    }

    public class mainclass
    {
        ListTable rolelist = new ListTable();
        private ListTable myClass= new ListTable();
        public void CheckRights()
        {
            IList<object> testlist = myClass.GetList();
            testlist.Add(new object[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 });   
        }
    }

    public class secondclass
    {
        private ListTable list=new ListTable();
        public void CheckRights(string username)
        {
            IList<object> called = list.GetList();
            foreach (object[] item in called)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(item[1].ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```